# Get original type of intercepted object in Unity

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container

How can I get the 'original' type of a proxy object which was intercepted by Unity's VirtualMethodInterceptor?
I've got something like:

```
T obj = (T)Intercept.NewInstance(typeof(T), new VirtualMethodInterceptor(), new[] { new MyInterceptor() });
```

then when I ask for the type of `obj` it will be something like `DynamicModule.ns.Wrapped_TheRealType_7615f35579e1442192a7aaf806733b7b`

How do I get `TheRealType`'s Type via code?

Answer (score 2):

You can descend the inheritance hierarchy of the generated type until you reach the correct one.

```cs
Type original = target.GetType();
while (original.Name.StartsWith("Wrapped_"))
{
  original = original.BaseType;
}
```

Not pretty but it should do the trick.

Comment: For VirtualMethod intercepted ones, that should work - for Interface-based ones you'll need to look at the Target property.

Comment: Yes, my question was for virtual method interception. I hoped there would be a better - not so tricky way, provided by Unity itself.

Comment: @Bond For the consumer it should be completely transparent that you use a generated proxy. I guess this is why Unity does not offer a way to identify the underlying target.

Comment: @SebastianWeber, yes I know that, and in my case there is no underlying target because I have only one instance(I don't have a proxy object) I just needed the original type that was inherited by the interceptor. Still can't believe that there is no built-in way of doing it.